# Socket IO to output a TCP socket message to a web page

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm experimenting with Node JS and Socket IO.
I took a look to the Socket.IO guide on Getting Started here:
https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ .
Here is the code:

for **index.js**

```
    var app = require('express')();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });

    io.on('connection', function(socket){
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
      });
    });

    http.listen(3000, function(){
      console.log('listening on *:3000');
    });
```

for **index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(){
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
  });
</script>

  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

On the same principle I tried to replace one of the partecipants in the chat with a computer. So I wrote some C++ code to connect to the port 3000 and send its own text message (just a simple string).

On the C++ side I had no problem in opening the socket, connecting, writing to the socket.
On the NODE JS the server listens to incoming connection on said port but it doesn't sense any client connecting.

How could I receive a message with the NODE server and send it for output on the web page ?

Side note: Just noticed that my C++ is using TCP protocol, raw data. Since Socket.IO is built on top of HTTP I think I should use HTTP instead. In this case I think I should build my HTTP request with a POST metod. Is it correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

socket.io is NOT a plain TCP socket and you cannot communicate with a socket.io server using a plain TCP message.

socket.io has it's own data frame layer on top of the webSocket protocol.  The webSocket protocol initiates all connections with an HTTP request and then "upgrades" and switches protocols to the webSocket protocol.

If you want to talk to a socket.io server from a C++ app, you need to get a socket.io client for C++.  Such client libraries for C++ do exist.  Here's the [implementation](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp) done by the socket.io folks.

---

If your web page is connecting via socket.io to your node.js server and you have a C++ app that you just want to send some data to your node.js program, then the simplest thing is to probably just have your C++ program send an HTTP request to the node.js server and have the node.js server programmed to listen for that request.  It doesn't sound like you need a continuous connection from your C++ app to your node.js server so you don't really need socket.io or webSocket for that.

Instead, just make an HTTP request from your C++ app to your a node.js HTTP server that is programmed to listen for and process that request.  The node.js server can then take whatever the data is and send it out to the connected webpages over the existing socket.io connections to those web pages.

Comment: Is it really no way to connect with socket.io with a plain TCP socket?

Comment: @JaredChu - There is no way unless you implement both the socket.io and webSocket protocols.  You can't even establish a socket.io connection without implementing a whole bunch of the protocol (which starts with an http request and then switches protocol to the webSocket protocol with a socket.io messaging layer on top of that.  In addition, the protocol establishes a bunch of stuff at the beginning of the connection (such as security keys) and you can't skip that stuff.  Then, to even send or receive a message, you have to use the proper data format from the protocol.